# EXT.Js api response data is not binding to store

Tags: extjs

I am facing an issue while calling a load method on the store.
My api is giving proper data, and i can see that in chrome network tab, However in the store object that data is missing
See sample code below

**Store Creation**

```
_createStore: function()
  {
    return new Ext.data.Store({
     proxy:
      {
      url: //api call which returns single object of below data feild  ,
      appName: 'myApp',
      appendIdForCreate: false,
      reader: {
        type: 'json'
      },
      fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'employeeId', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'start', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'end', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'details', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'audits', type: 'auto' },
        .
        .
        .
        .
        ....... Some more properties
      ]
    });
  },
```

### **Sample API Response**

```
{
    "id": 1234567,
    "employeeId": 123456,
    "start": "2022-01-13T00:00:00",
    "end": "2022-01-13T00:00:00",
    "details": [{
            "detailId": "123456789",
            "date": "2022-01-13T00:00:00",
            "startOfWeek": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ],
  
    "audits": [{
            "timestamp": "2022-01-10T04:24:43",
            "comment": "test comment",
            "authorLastName": "Naikele",
            "authorFirstName": "Sagar"
        }]
}
```

When i call
var myStore=_createStore();
myStore.load();

I am getting data properly from API, I can see that in the chrome network tab
But I do not find any data in myStore
Don't know what's wrong I am doing!
Store data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh6bc.jpg)

API response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIkuL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy does not have a `field` property. Define your model like:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    },{
        name: 'employeeId',
        type: 'int'
    } // additional fields
    ],
});
```

Then use this model when you create your store. Also it is a good idea to set type of proxy as well:

```
return new Ext.data.Store({
  model: 'MyModel',
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax' // or 'rest' etc
    url: 'url',
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Koltai, I appreciate your quick response, Apologies for the confusion, I do not have fields property in the proxy section, it's independent, I will try out your suggestion.

Comment: I debugged code further and found var root = helper.isNullOrUndefinedOrWhitespace(config.pathRoot) ? 'data' : config.pathRoot;
    Ext.apply(config, {
      reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: root
      },

Comment: If there is no root property (e.g. `data`) in your response, add this to the proxy declaration: `reader: { type: "json", root: ""}`.

Comment: the issue got resolved, the main problem with the in the proxy, root path of JSON, for me there is no root property, however, it was taking default root as data as per my project,

Comment: Good to hear your problem is solved.